# PowerShell on Target Machines -TFS task, Security Warning persists after changing execution policy in remote server

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, remote-server

I am pulling my hairs as I could not figure out what happens in powershell on target machine task (v1.0 and 2.0) in my release.
every time I run the task, it throws me the error:

```
 AuthorizationManager check failed. ---> System.Management.Automation.PSSecurityException: AuthorizationManager check failed. ---> System.Management.Automation.Host.HostException: A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message: Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning message. Do you want to run \\server\c$\Program Files\exampleps.ps1?
```

I understand this may relate to execution policy, so this is what I have done so far trying to solve the issue:

1. I went in the remote server and turned off IE enhanced security for admins, as the service account to run this script is admin
2. Shift+Right-click powershell to run as service account and changed execution policy from remotesigned to bypass. performed this action in both 32 and 64bit powershell. Bypass was set to local machine and current user
3. Added the  \server\c$\Program Files\exampleps.ps1 to trusted site under internet options

I have tried to google and stackoverflow similar questions and these are what I found.

**Update**

*After trying all 3 methods above, even when I try to run the ps script directly in console, the security warning still shows up. For some reasons, the bypass execution policy doesn't kick in.* --I was able to run it in console without warnings, however, tfs task still failed

I am really frustrated and I hope anyone in the community can give me some guidance on the this.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Can you try  and see what happens when you run unblock-file -path ""

Comment: I did try unblock-file -path cmdlet, it allowed me to execute the script in console without warning. However, the powershell on remote machine task in release still failed.

Comment: seems the bypass execution kicked in so I can run the ps script without warning in console with service account, but TFS release task still failed for same reason...

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following ways to see if they can work:

1. **Use the "Bypass" Execution Policy Flag**

   ```
   PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \server\c$\Program Files\exampleps.ps1
   ```
2. **Read Script from the File and Pipe to PowerShell Standard In**

   ```
   Get-Content \server\c$\Program Files\exampleps.ps1 | PowerShell.exe -noprofile -
   ```
3. **Use the Invoke-Expression Command**

   ```
   Get-Content \server\c$\Program Files\exampleps.ps1 | Invoke-Expression
   ```
4. **Use the "Unrestricted" Execution Policy Flag**

   ```
   PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted -File \server\c$\Program Files\exampleps.ps1
   ```

There also are few other ways you can try. To view more details, you can reference to "[**15 Ways to Bypass the PowerShell Execution Policy**](https://blog.netspi.com/15-ways-to-bypass-the-powershell-execution-policy/)".

Comment: I am thinking where that warning came from, as I have set  execution policy in target machine as bypass to local machine and admin account. the agent sits in another RM and doesnt have such issue to other servers. it just has this issue in 1 server, The Powershell on Target Machine (v1.*) calls the script (which is located in another server) with UNC path, so these inline commands may work but not applicable in my case. Thanks tho.

Comment: Hi @Wei, you can try directly calling the same PowerShell script file on the agent machine. If the same warning returned, the warning should be came from the agent machine system's policy. If the warning does not occur on the agent machine but in the pipeline, the warning may be came from the policy of the TFS server. Normally, Azure DevOps has it default security strategy may be applied to the agent when running the pipelines.

Comment: thanks for the information. I tired to run the powershell script directly in agent machine and it started the process without warning. To your point- " the warning may be came from the policy of the TFS server", can it affect only 1 server tho? I currently have similar task setting for other environments and they all go through smoothly. If so, what explicitly policy do you mean in TFS server? Thanks very much.

Comment: continued with previous comment, is this something related to server config?

Comment: Hi @Wei, the policy may be applied when using the PowerShell task in the pipeline. How about using the command Unblock-File script_name.ps1 before calling the script file?